# appending urls contianing random characters

Tags: regex, string

I'm new to regular expressions. I've spent the better part of two days searching for an answer with no luck. I want to append some urls in some "plist" files to add "download" to the end of each. Each url has a unique string of four characters like below. I have about 800 urls to modify. Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
www.somesite.com/c8hj/
www.somesite.com/Lp4V/
www.somesite.com/zbro/
etc.

www.somesite.com/c8hj/download
www.somesite.com/Lp4V/download
www.somesite.com/zbro/download
```

Comment: Do you only want to modify urls from a specific list of paths? If so, is that list in a file, one name per line. Are you using Linux?

Comment: If you still want the regex maybe something like [Online Demo](http://regex101.com/r/uH4sY5/1) could work

Answer (score 1):

You can use a really simple regex like this:

```
$
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/hP9xN4/1)**

[image]

Although you could simply use notepad++ and create a Macro for that.

Comment: Sorry. I'm really new at all this. What I should have said is that these these urls/text strings are scattered throughout a file, not at the end of lines.

Comment: @pureenergy777 I see. You can check this link http://regex101.com/r/hP9xN4/2 with a working example

Comment: @pureenergy777 if you want the python code enter in the link I sent you and go to Code Generator section.

Comment: Sorry. What language will the regex you sent work in?

Comment: @pureenergy777 it works on python, php and javascript.

Comment: The random text is more like     AA8AAAAEEAAAVAAAAAAAAAAFEAAArAAAAAAAAAAQEAAA
          <key>goToURL</key>
          <string>https://www.somesite.com/whlb/</string>
          <key>openInNewWindow</key>
div&gt;&lt;div&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;&lt;b&gt;worked in partnership&amp;nbsp;&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/dispan style="font-size: 14px;"&gt;&amp;nbsp; &amp;nbspp;nbsp;2. effectively remediate repeated errors&lt;
https://www.somesite.com/d9R7/